# How to upload to firebase storage using this uri?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Upload succeeded if imageUri was in this form.
content://com.android.providers.media.documents/document/image%3A12305

But this form failed
/document/image:10674

And I got this Toast message.

"An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response."

I'd appreciate it if you could give me any hints.

What I tried

1.Get Image from gallery

```
Uri imageUri;
StorageTask uploadTask;
StorageReference storageReference;

 @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    File compressedImageFile; //for compress library : https://github.com/zetbaitsu/Compressor

    if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null && data.getData() != null) {

        Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();

        try {
            compressedImageFile = new Compressor(getContext()).compressToFile(new File(selectedImageUri.getPath()));

            imageUri = data.getData(); //this works well but uploaded original size.
//                imageUri =Uri.fromFile(compressedImageFile); //fail
//                imageUri= Uri.fromFile(new File(compressedImageFile.toURI().getPath())); //fail
//                imageUri= Uri.parse(new File(compressedImageFile.getPath()).toString()); //fail

            if (uploadTask != null && uploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Upload in preogress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                uploadImage();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

2.uploadImage();

```
 if (imageUri != null) {
        final StorageReference fileReference = storageReference.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                + "." + getFileExtension(imageUri));

        uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(imageUri);
        uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
            @Override
            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {                      
                    throw task.getException();
                }
                return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
            }
        }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {                      
                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                    String mUri = downloadUri.toString();

                    reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Users").child(fuser.getUid());
                    HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
                    map.put("imageURL", "" + mUri);
                    reference.updateChildren(map);                        
                } else {                       
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Very nice way to put up your question.

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying this way.

Answer (score 0):

По пробуйте это

```
StorageReference riversRef = 
storageRef.child("images/"+imageUri.getLastPathSegment());
uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(imageUri);

// Register observers to listen for when the download is done or if it 
//fails
uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads
}
}).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
@Override
public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
    // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, 
   //content-type, etc.
  
   }
   });
```

Comment: Please use english in your answers. Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

add this code into your file :-

```
StorageReference storageReference;
storageReference = storage.getReference();

final StorageReference ref = storageReference.child("images/" + UUID.randomUUID());
        ref.putFile(your file path)
          .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> ()  {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        ref.getDownloadUrl().addOnSuccessListener(new 
    OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onSuccess(Uri imageUrl{



                            }
                        });
                    }
                })
                .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        Toast.makeText(IndivudualChatActivity.this, "Failed " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                })
                .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot
                                .getTotalByteCount());

                    }
                });
```